# Native laptop keyboard not recognised when asked for disk encryption upon reboot

Tags: keyboard, encryption, laptop, luks, surface

Linux amateur here, I have a Microsoft Surface laptop 2, running Ubuntu 22.4 with the organic ubuntu disk encryption (LUKs I believe) disk encryption. When the device is rebooted, it asks to unlock the disk, which is all well and good except that my laptops native keyboard does not let me type in the key. When I plus in an external keyboard, I am able to type in the key no problem, then when the log screen shows, the native keyboard works fine.

This is just inconvenient at home however with some travel in the near future, I'd like to have my devices encryption during travel, particularly at high risk areas such as airports and boarder crossings, and carrying around an external keyboard is both impractical and unsafe.

Whats my next move, is there a way to fix this ? I am new to linux and am excited to learn from everyone so please give as much information as you're able too.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Why would you need to encrypt system files? It makes no sense at all. This may cause some trouble as you noticed. You can encrypt only your personal files in `/home`.